# Redirect TCP traffic of a third-party libary

Tags: python, networking, tcp, portforwarding

**Szenario:** Can I force the TCP traffic of a libary (not Python, f.e. a database client) through a Python socket I created?

The Background is, that I create this socket to connect through a SOCKS5 Proxy to the remote host.

A solution I read about is SSH tunneling, but this would require the remote host to be ssh enabled. Due to security considerations this might not be given in an production environment.

Is there a solution that I can realise directly in Python? I am thinking of a "Internal Port Forwarder" that listens on say localhost:4444 - I tell the libary to send the traffic to localhost:4444 - but the "Internal Port Forwarder" just sends the traffic via the open socket.

```
--------------------------------------     -------------     
| Host A                             |     | Host B    |                              
|                                    |     |           |               
| Libary ->  Internal Port Forwarder ------->          |
|                                    |     |           |
--------------------------------------     -------------
```

What did I think of: I looked at SSH Tunneling using paramiko and creating a own TCP server with the socket module. The latter looks promising, but I am not sure if this is the most elegant way to achive this. [Here is a link to a working gist of the custom port forwarder](https://gist.github.com/fyx99/10fb8196dc41fb90dcb23d7ee722babc), but I imagine that this will be quite unstable (maybe the libary creates more than one connection and the connection is long lasting etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> Redirect TCP traffic of a third-party libary

The traditional way to do this was always via
LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD,
so a C library that asks for a TCP connection
will go through Socksify or through the
[tsocks](https://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php)
transparent SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I understand, that using the env variables would be kind of an operating system solution. I found a bunch of implementations of transparent proxies in Python ([tsocks](https://github.com/jun7th/tsocks), [pr0cks](https://pypi.org/project/pr0cks/)) that essentially do the same thing as me in the example (but better). Any  advantage/disadvantage?